# RecycleView and ScreenManager problems

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Can't seem to solve getting data from my database to populate into various textinputs when using Recycleview. The problem exist only when i use ScreenManager/Screen. When i call the screen directly from the `def build(self): return Screen` everything works but not when i call the screen manager like this `def build(self): return ScreenManager`

> kv file

```
<Button>:
    on_press: app.root.get_data(*args)
<Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint_x: .3
        RV:
            viewclass: 'Button'
            data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in root.my_data]
            RecycleBoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                default_size: None, dp(32)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
```

Comment: When you do `return Screen` it returns your widget from your kv file named `Screen`. ScreenManager is used when you have multiple screens you want to switch between. Since you haven't defined a class named `ScreenManager` anywhere, I'm guessing your app is just a blank screen. There are some good videos on youtube (including by me!) on how to work with screens / screenmanagers in kivy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `get_data()` and variable, my_data are implemented in class Screen. Without ScreenManager, the root is Screen. After adding ScreenManager, now the root is ScreenManager. In order to access the method `get_data()` from the class rule, Button, you need to do the following:

- Add `id: screen_rv` after you have instantiated class rule, `<Screen>` under `ScreenManager`
- Replace `app.root.get_data(*args)` with `app.root.ids.screen_rv.get_data(*args)`

## kv - Snippets

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    ScreenRV:
        id: screen_rv

<Button>:
    on_press: app.root.ids.screen_rv.get_data(*args)

<ScreenRV>:
    name: 'screen_rv'
```

Comment: You are most welcome. Thank you for the positive feedback.